# Change Trigger order in BasedOn / inherited Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, blend

I have a base `Style` - `DataGridRowSelectionStyle`. On some `DataGrids` I need to extend this `Style` to ink the `background`.

#### DataGridRowSelectionStyle

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="DataGridRowSelectionStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DataGrid_Row_IsMouseOver}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DataGrid_Row_IsSelected}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### RowStyle

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowSelectionStyle}">                                        
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="{x:Static production1:ProcessDataEval.OK}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DGLB_Green}"/>                                                
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="{x:Static production1:ProcessDataEval.NG}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DGLB_Red}"/>                                                
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Because of the `Trigger` order, the two base `Triggers` are overwritten and `IsMouseOver` or `IsSelected` is not triggered anymore.

---

**Solution 1**: Extend the `RowStyle`. Very bad solution, because I would not need my base `Style` anymore..

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowSelectionStyle}">                                        
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="{x:Static production1:ProcessDataEval.OK}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DGLB_Green}"/>                                                
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="{x:Static production1:ProcessDataEval.NG}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DGLB_Red}"/>                                                
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DataGrid_Row_IsMouseOver}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DataGrid_Row_IsSelected}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**Solution 2**: Create a `behavior` and add it to the base `Style` which would reorder the final `Style`.
Problem: `Behavior<TriggerCollection>` or `Behavior<Style>` is not working!

> The type 'System.Windows.Style' must be convertible to 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' in order to use it as paramter 'T' in the generic class 'System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior'

---

Someone got a solution how to use a `behavior` in a Style or how to change the trigger order in the inherited `Style`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution by using an `AttachedProperty`.

I cache every Trigger with an index for the final `TriggerCollection`. After the `DataGridRow` is rendered, `else if (d is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)` is `true` and the `Style` gets cloned with a new order of the `Triggers`.

```
public static class TriggerAttachedBehavior
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Trigger, int> _Triggers = new Dictionary<Trigger, int>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets property value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attachedObj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int GetOderIndex(Trigger attachedObj)
    {
        return (int)attachedObj.GetValue(OderIndexProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets property value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attachedObj"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public static void SetOderIndex(Trigger attachedObj, int value)
    {
        attachedObj.SetValue(OderIndexProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="OderIndexProperty"/> DependencyProperty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OderIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("OderIndex", typeof(int), typeof(TriggerAttachedBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(-1, OderIndexChangedCallback));

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when OderIndexProperty has changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">Dependency object.</param>
    /// <param name="args">Event arguments.</param>
    private static void OderIndexChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is Trigger attachedObj)
        {
            _Triggers.Add(attachedObj, (int)args.NewValue);
        }
        else if (d is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
        {
            // clone style with trigger lock
            var newStyle = new Style(frameworkElement.Style.TargetType, frameworkElement.Style);
            newStyle.Triggers.Clear();

            // add all triggers except the base
            foreach (TriggerBase triggerBase in frameworkElement.Style.Triggers)
            {
                if(_Triggers.Any(t => _Equals(t.Key, triggerBase)))
                    continue;    
                newStyle.Triggers.Add(triggerBase);
            }

            // add the base class triggers
            foreach (int i in _Triggers.Values.OrderBy(t => t))
            {
                newStyle.Triggers.Add(_Triggers.First(t => t.Value == i).Key);
            }

            // apply new style
            frameworkElement.Style = newStyle;
        }
    }

    private static bool _Equals(TriggerBase x, TriggerBase y)
    {
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType())
            return false;

        switch (x)
        {
            case DataTrigger dataTrigger:
                return false;
            case EventTrigger eventTrigger:
                return false;
            case MultiDataTrigger multiDataTrigger:
                return false;
            case MultiTrigger multiTrigger:
                return false;
            case Trigger trigger:
                return trigger.Property.Name.Equals((y as Trigger).Property.Name);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="DataGridRowSelectionStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowDefaultStyle}">
    <Setter Property="behaviors:TriggerAttachedBehavior.OderIndex" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" behaviors:TriggerAttachedBehavior.OderIndex="998">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DataGrid_Row_IsMouseOver}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" behaviors:TriggerAttachedBehavior.OderIndex="999">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DataGrid_Row_IsSelected}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MultiDataTrigger` can be used to paint rows based on their status value *only when* IsMouseOver is false and IsSelected is false. Additional conditions (when they are met) prevent MultiDataTriggers from overriding base Triggers:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowSelectionStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="{x:Static production1:ProcessDataEval.OK}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DGLB_Green}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger >
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding CurrentStatus}" Value="{x:Static production1:ProcessDataEval.NG}"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{extensions:Theme Key=DGLB_Red}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Is that also your personal solution how you would solve this problem? If you change your base Style after 6 month, it could be possible that you have to fix all inherited styles including customer projects. (The style is part of a framework library and each customer gets a personal application)